# Minimum kinetic energy for an endoergic reaction to happen?

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics

If the deuteron nucleus is incident on a stationary nitrogen nucleus, what is the minimum kinetic energy required for the deuteron so that the reaction can occur?

$$\rm ^{1}_{0}n + {}^{235}_{92}U \to + {}^{144}_{56}Ba +{}^{89}_{36}Kr + 3{}^{1}_{0}n$$$$

We know that the reaction energy is Q = -10,14MeV (Endoergic reaction), we have the masses in atomic units for both particles obviously and then what I did was solve for:

$$E_k = E_{k_1} + E_{k_2}$$ and then I'm a bit insecure if momentum is conserved and if it is then I end up with:

$$E_{k_1} = E_k\frac{m_2}{m_2+m_1}$$ where mass 1 is for the deuteron nucleus and mass 2 for nitrogen, but in my book they give me:

$$E_{k_1}=E_{k_{cm}}\frac{m_2+m_1}{m_2}$$
So obviously I'm wondering why and how they got that expression since they only give it like this in the book.

Comment: What reaction? ..................

Comment: Sorry, added the reaction but only the left side is needed for this particular question though since the previous exercise was to find the reaction energy of the entire reaction as stated above.

Comment: I don't believe that neutron-induced fission of U-235 *absorbs* energy...